# Is it possibly to apply CSS based on user?

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-online

Is it possible to apply CSS according to the type of user and/or his permissions? (e.g., admin, regular users, etc...)

For example, I'd like to hide the #s4-ribbonrow for regular users since they will not be allowed to modify pages but I'd like to leave this displayed for admins since they need to be able to save a page after editing.

I'm using SP2013 Online

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can update the master page and then use security trimming as below

1. Open your SharePoint master page
2. Locate this line:

   ```
   <div id="s4-ribbonrow" class="s4-pr s4-ribbonrowhidetitle">
   ```
3. Change it to:

   ```
   <div id="s4-ribbonrow" class="s4-pr s4-ribbonrowhidetitle" style="display:none">
   ```
4. Now find the end of the “s4-ribbonrow” tag and add following block right after it:

   ```
   <Sharepoint:SPSecurityTrimmedControl ID="SPSecurityTrimmedControl2" runat="server" PermissionsString="AddAndCustomizePages">
       <script type="text/javascript">
       document.getElementById("s4-ribbonrow").style.display = "block";
       </script>
    </Sharepoint:SPSecurityTrimmedControl>
   ```
5. Save the new master page and publish it.

[Source](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/zwsong/archive/2010/04/29/how-to-hide-ribbon-from-users-without-edit-page-privilege.aspx)